# Какой алгоритм хеширования лучше использовать?

Tags: криптография, пароль, хеширование

Сейчас много говорится о том, что md5 становится очень уязвимым. Как надежно шифровать данные? Использовать md5 с разными ухищрениями или какой-то другой алгоритм? Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как лучше

Comment: Какие данные собираетесь шифровать ?

Кргда говорят об уязвимости md5 обычно имеют в виду получение хэша от **пароля** (т.е. короткой строки).

Comment: Вообще, нечто более простое: числа. Собираюсь добавить много-много соли. Это поможет?

Comment: поможет и немного соли... если хочешь надежней, сделай соль уникальную для каждого юзера

Comment: Подумал как раз об этом. Спасибо

Comment: @Vasilesk, Вы пишете, что хотите хэшировать числа. 

С какой целью ? Зашифровать последовательность чисел ? Или хотите сделать хэш таблицу для их поиска ?

Answer (score 2):

Вся уязвимость таких популярных алгоритмов хеширования, как MD5, MD4, SHA-1 и т.д заключается в поиске коллизий, так называемых сходных хэшей для разных кодируемых строк.
Где-то вероятность нахождения коллизии больше, где-то меньше. В алгоритме MD5 первая находка псевдоколлизии была осуществлена аж в 1996. А вообще, если вам интересны подробности, то советую почитать [вот эту статью](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Answer (score 0):

Вот php функция генерирующая хеши очень случайно

```
function hash_generate($data)
{
    $data =  sha1(md5($data)) . md5(sha1($data));
    $preg = preg_split('//', $data);
    $rand = mt_rand(0, count($preg)-3);
    $symb = array('_', '-', '.', '=', '+');
    $data = str_replace($data[$rand], $symb[mt_rand(0, count($symb)-1)], $data);

    return $data;
}

echo hash_generate(time());
```

к сожалению нет времени превратить это в что-то толковое, что будет обрабатывать и разбирать все нагенерированное!

Comment: А ваш хеш будет одинаковый при одинаковых входных данных? mt_rand все же.

Поэтому проверять пароль по этому хешу не получится.

Comment: В чем смысл этой функции ? 

Получить некую уникальную и непредсказываемую строку символов ? 

Для каких целей предлагается ее использовать ?

Comment: это вообще не хэш а псевдослучайная последовательность данных сгенерированная на основе ключа (в данном конкретном случае в качестве ключа выступают массив входных данных)